# What is the output in a RNN?

Tags: neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

I have recently been looking for some information about recurrent neural networks. Some people use a layer between the hidden state and the output and other ones use the hidden state as output.

What would be correct? and why do they use both ones?

Thank you!

[RNN with output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN0PF.png)

[RNN output is hidden state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS9jn.png)

Comment: Surely by definition the last layer is output. Are you sure you don't mean that some RNNs have a layer between input and output and others don't?

Comment: I have seen that some people refer to the hidden state also as the output of the RNN, and others pass the hidden state through another layer to obtain the output of the network.

Comment: It might help if you had a hidden-as-output source to quote so we can see in context what they do.

Comment: (Sorry If didn't make me understand, I am not an English speaker) The second image shows that you have the same value for the hidden state and the output.

Comment: Surely no layer would exactly reproduce the values of the previous layer; there'd be no point in adding such a layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it depends what you want to do. I tend to view RNNs as doing two things at every time step $t$, conceptually: (1) updating their hidden state $h_t$ and (2) emitting some prediction or action $a_t$.
Clearly, *both* of these can be useful, but for different reasons.

More specifically, let $x_t$ be the input at time $t$ in the current sequence. Then we might do something like:
$$ h_t = g(x_t,h_{t-1}) $$ $$ a_t = f(h_t) $$

Notice that mathematically we could just have $f(h)=h$, in which case the output at time $t$ *is* the hidden state itself. This is obviously a simplified case of the RNN.

E.g., in reinforcement learning, $h_t$ might represent the internal representation of the state/environment at time $t$, while $a_t$ is the action performed by the agent at time $t$. Clearly $a_t$ is a useful output (it controls the agent), but $h_t$ can be passed to a planning algorithm for example or used for other tasks than just determining the next action.

Or, in translation, some approaches (like [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3215)) feed in the input sentence to one RNN $R_1$ and take the hidden state $h_T$ as output (as it holds the network's internal representation of the full sentence, conceptually speaking), and then feed $h_T$ as the starting hidden state to another RNN $R_2$. The per-time-step outputs of $R_1$ are not important. For $R_2$, it's inputs are *the last word it output*; i.e., $x_t=a_{t-1}$ for $R_2$. The sequence $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_N)$ from $R_2$ is the output sentence. So for $R_1$, the "output" is $h_T$, while for $R_2$ it is $a$.

All of this is just to say that *both* are useful outputs and are used as such in different ways in practice.

Comment: You forgot to mention the most important part, namely how each word in the output sequence $a_1 ... a_N$ is generated. For such a case, $f(h_t) = \text{softmax}(W_o h_t + b_o)$, where $W_o$ is a matrix that transforms $h_t$ to a vector of the size of the vocabulary. (The softmax can then be seen as a probability distribution from which you sample $a_t$.)